# Remove Android tab toolbar menu top spacing/padding

Tags: android, padding, spacing, tabmenu

Thanks in advance guys.
I've searched and experimented with this simple issue for ages with no luck

(see pic below)

-I've got a tabbed menu bar that opens initially with a lot of padding/spacing at the top.

-I want to remove this and lock the tab menu right under the main bar (no scroll).

-Currently, as the window scrolls down the spacing disappears and the tab menu looks as it should.

-No amount of messing with padding settings seems to lock it in place without the spacing.

-Setting it to not scroll fixes it in place but keeps the annoying spacing at the top.

-Seemingly the excessive spacing seems to be the exact size of the top menu bar

[image]

Comment: Trying using a no action bar theme on the activity!

Comment: show your layout xml. you can try adding a <CoordinatorLayout> as the root of your xml.